# How can I get the arguments on a command-line with vanila python?

Tags: python

lets suppose I have a file called this.py
when I run this on the terminal

```
this.py
```

how can I get all the arguments passed? such as:

```
this.py -foo
```

I do not want to use argparse, just vanila python

lets say this.py is this:

```py
#user/python_projects/this.py/
arguments = """ now here I need to find a way of a list of the arguments passed"""
def main(arguments):
    if arguments[0] == 'foo':
        print('bar')
    else:
        print('I like foo ):')
main(arguments)
```

If I use

```
this.py -foo
```

then the expected result is:
'bar'

Comment: is it ok to use `sys.argv`?

Comment: I think it is :), ill take a look. thanks

Comment: @richyen yep, it is perfect

Comment: For advanced use cases, take a look at `argparse` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @MohammadJavadNaderi Thanks, but read the post again

Comment: @rafa_rrayes Oh, Sorry!

Comment: I would agree with @MohammadJavadNaderi if it weren't for what you said in the original question, but perhaps you could help improve the original question by telling us *why* you can't use `argparse`?

Comment: @MohammadJavadNaderi No problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sys`, you should be able to make it work:

```
$ cat this.py 
import sys
arguments = sys.argv
def main(arguments):
    if arguments[1] == 'foo':
        print('bar')
    else:
        print('I like foo ):')
main(arguments)

$ python this.py foo
bar
```

Note that your example used `argument[0]` when I think you really wanted `argument[1]`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the solution I was looking for! 
I just removed the first element like this:
`
del arguments[0] # this element would be the name of the script or the path
`